# How to unparent child

Tags: python, game-engine

I want to unparent a child from empty with python using `obj = own.children` but it wont work with unparenting because this 1 child object is classifed as list or smth else, and gets zombie object spam in console.

how to unparent child without using name?

Comment: children seems to be read-only go the other way ( get the child object and remove his parent )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use the `removeParent()` function, since both `.children` and `.parent` are read only :

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

for child in own.children :
    child.removeParent()
```