# I want to unparent an object with python

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to unparent an object.

I tried the following code

```
import bpy

selectedList = bpy.context.selected_objects
selectedList[0].removeParent()
```

However, the following error occurred and the parent could not be removed.

```
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'removeParent'
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

How can I make a selected object have no parent?

Comment: Related  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154848/clear-parent-and-keep-transformation The properties and methods of `bpy` objects follow a convention that they are in lower case.  If you see something like `ob.removeParent()` in blender code, chances are it's for the [game engine module `bge`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27541/how-to-unparent-child)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

Assume you have an object in python `obj`:

Try `obj.parent = None`

**None** is a keyword refer to nothing. You assign the object parent to nothing is equivalent to remove parent.

#### Solution 2:

Directly modified data in object without operator can lead to some problem. You can clear the parent in your blender, and in **info panel** you should see the [python command](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.parent_clear): `bpy.ops.object.parent_clear(type='CLEAR')`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the object to keep its position on the World coordinates, this is a more complete solution without using the Blender operators `bpy.ops`

```
world_loc = ob.matrix_world.to_translation()
ob.parent = None
ob.matrix_world.translation = world_loc
```